# Please add an RSS feed for the careers site

Tags: feature-request, jobs, feed

I like the quick little stats page you land on when you go to the careers site, but it would be nice if this had some kind of RSS functionality. I don't like to check the sites, I like the sites to update me.

Comment: In Soviet Russia, the sites update YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd have to be authenticated RSS, because that's not public. So you'd have to feed it your auth cookie. Just letting you know..

Comment: Why couldn't the stats be public?

Comment: I guess that's another question: how much of your CV should be public? right now, it's a private service entirely. Public face: SO. Private face: SOC.

Comment: @Rich B - public stats could mean a hiring person might be influenced by the higher number of "CV Views" someone has.

Comment: @seanmonstar: I didn't say it would be publicly browsable.

Comment: @Jeff: Agreed. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24926