# How much of your profile on careers.stackoverflow.com should be public facing?

Tags: discussion, jobs

How much of your profile (if any) on careers.stackoverflow.com should be public facing?

This came up in my last [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24912).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

None of it.

If I wanted it public, I'd just put it on my website.

Comment: What about the stats as mentioned in the linked question?

Comment: Would be great if they came up with an authentication method that worked with Google Reader...

Comment: I could agree with that. But making the information available without authentication but without browsing would seem to be fine to me.

Comment: Something like a random UID as an RSS link attached to your account, with the information being sent to RSS not identifying the user.

Comment: Security via obscurity? I'd be fine with that - if anyone is careless enough (or open enough) to post the link to their feed publicly, then it's on their head if something bad happens (of course, SOC could provide users a way to revoke / regenerate feed URLs too).

Comment: @Shog9: Agreed. Glad we have solved this issue. Email it to Jeff and tell him I said to do it.

Answer (score 5):

It definitely shouldn't be public by default.

That said, I'd like to see an option to have select parts of my CV viewable from some public URL. (ex. careers.stackoverflow.com/{username})

Perhaps a Public/Private checkbox next to each piece of information on the CV, with everything set to Private by default.

Right now I'm using my public Linked-In profile as my resume.

- I can export out a well formatted PDF copy of my resume to print or e-mail to recruiters or potential employers.
- I can link to my public profile online.

I like the SO community and the style and mind-set of the sites. I would love to host my 'digital resume' in this environment instead of Linked-In.

Comment: I like the idea of making it customizable.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing this is so it can be up/down voted as an option:

> There should be a way to permalink to a careers profile.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on the blog, I have **no idea** how this will work in terms of your *current* employer snooping to try to identify likely runaways. [Not a huge problem for me at the minute](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/06/checking-your-career-path.html), but in particular people like me and Jon would probably be readily identifiable... UK, MVP (or ex-MVP for Jon), high volume in C#, etc.

I don't know an awful lot about the jobs markets - but I'd be... *cautious* - or I'd want to see exactly what browsing employers would see ;-p

Comment: And at least see who the employers are.