# Privacy on Stackoverflow Careers

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

If a user doesn't want their current employer to know that they're keeping their ears open on the job market, when filling out their CV it's not clear at all what potential hiring managers will see when browsing the profiles.

Will ones employer be able to see names if casually surfing the site?  Will the see other information?  And does a potential employer need to get behind the paywall before seeing profiles, or can anyone see them?

Comment: good q by the way, I haven't documented much of the employer side and this is something you certainly have a right to know.

Comment: Essentially my thoughts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24926/how-much-of-your-profile-on-careers-stackoverflow-com-should-be-public-facing/24949#24949

Comment: what's wrong with my employer seeing me as having a CV posted.. anywhere? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247217/do-you-actively-look-for-a-better-job

Answer (score 13):

> does a potential employer need to get behind the paywall before seeing profiles

Yes! **No payment, no viewing of details for employers.** They can do trial searches and see preview counts of results but no actual user details. And believe me, they pay .. uh .. a *lot* for the privilege of viewing actual user information, so this is not something that should happen casually.

> Will ones employer be able to see names if casually surfing the site? Will the see other information?

No, they must pay the (much!) higher employer subscription rate first.

Now, if you have paid to file a Stack Overflow Careers CV, and your employer just happens to sign up for a paid Stack Overflow Careers employer account, too .. then yes, they'd be able to find you. It's sort of a catch-22 but I don't know how to get around that, since the same problem exists on every other job site that I can think of..

Comment: Re "the same problem" - I'm not sure it does; most seem to be the applicant choosing from potential employers. Often the employer names aren't given, but if they see something that sounds *remarkably* like their employer (same location, same technology, etc) - then they simply don't apply.

Comment: How much will this cost employers?

Comment: Isn't this a check on candidate->employer != employer->name? Granted, I haven't visited the careers site yet.

Comment: @Brian: they could do that, but it would be far from perfect.  How would you handle slight differences in names?

Comment: That's why your posting your **CV** not your **resume**!  An employer shouldn't be upset you have your CV up, or at least you could spin it like that.

Comment: @Joel - Some sort of auto complete could work (I'd suggest that it's only done on the candidate side), but it still has the issue of a candidate miss-spelling, then the employer signing up with the correct spelling (it could also lead to either large js files or more http requests, depending on how it is implemented).

Comment: @Brian: It already has an auto completition feature, I noticed when I filled out the details of my educational history that it auto-offered the name of my school after the first few characters.

Comment: @DrJokepu, yes that works for schools, but if the employer name auto-completes, that can only mean that someone else has already entered it - so the employer will be suspicious anyway ;)

Comment: @Michael: If CV is something "far more comprehensive" than resume (Wikipedia), how should *that* not upset an employer if a resume does? Careers front page seems to use the terms pretty much interchangeably: "Unlike traditional resumes, a Stack Overflow CV gives..." You can try to spin it like that, sure, but I'm not sure who would buy that...

Comment: How about hide my results from employers whose name match "Fog*"

Comment: @Bob The problem wit that is that if you work in the Fog Industry and are currently employed by FogStreet, what happens when FogWorld comes knocking? You've just knocked out a potential employer because their name is similar.

Comment: @docgnome - Well, then we just make it a regex.  I can't wait for the flood of employer-name-regex questions that will spawn on SO... ;)